# Specifying wireless network name with accent in wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

How can I configure `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to connect to a network that has an accent in its SSID? The name of the network is of form `Réseau de XL1`.

If I use `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan|grep SSID` I see the network appears as:

```
ESSID:"R\xC3\xA9seau de MP1"
```

At the moment I have the following the `wpa_supplicant` file (actual values modified):

```
network={
        ssid="Réseau de XL1"
        psk="!reseau_2014!"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Checking the encoding of '\xC3\xA9' this suggests it is a UTF8 representation of 'é', but I am not sure if wpa_supplicant is interpreting it as UTF8?

Comment: You can code an ssid as a hex string. `ssid=52C3A973656175206465204D5031` no quotes.

Comment: Interesting. How would I get the ssid as a hex string?

Comment: I converted that string from your `iw list` command with `od` and after echoing it into a file with `hexedit`.

Comment: google `ascii to hex converter`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to code it in hex as

```
ssid=52C3A973656175206465204D5031
```

You can generate the hex value with `echo "Réseau de XL1" | xxd -p | tr a-z A-Z`

Comment: Should probably clarify how to generate the hex. For example: `echo "Réseau de XL1" | xxd -p | tr a-z A-Z`, paying attention to the resultant values, since in one instance I did get an issue due to UTF-8 combining characters.

Comment: This `iwlist  wlan0 scan | awk -F"\"" '/ESSID:/ {print $2}' | xxd -p | tr a-z A-Z` is the most automatic way to generate the hex ssid.

Answer (score 1):

Just replying to myself following some testing.

- Escaping the network name appears to work: `R\xC3\xA9seau de MP1`
- In my local setup using `hexdump -C` I see the encoding is UTF8 (probably a side effect of using a UTF8 based terminal)
- Also looking at the [docs](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf), for the network block, I see:

```
# ssid: SSID (mandatory); network name in one of the optional formats:
#   - an ASCII string with double quotation
#   - a hex string (two characters per octet of SSID)
#   - a printf-escaped ASCII string P"<escaped string>"
```

So I ended up with:

```
network={
        # ssid: Réseau de XL1
        ssid="R\xC3\xA9seau de XL1"
        psk="!reseau_2014!"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Based on the docs I'll stick with the escaping, since that is probably safer in terms of various possible terminal encodings, even if UTF8 is likely predominate.